# Upgrade Visual Studio Setup to WiX

Tags: wix

I migrated a Visual Studio Setup Project to WiX.
If I upgrade the Software installed by WiX with a WiX Setup (increased Minor Version), it upgrades fine.
But If I try to upgrade the Software installed by VS Setup, with my new WiX Setup, it does not remove the old Installation. And I kept the same Upgrade Id.

Is this not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does it do? You get two entries in Programs and Features after you try to do the upgrade?

If the upgrade codes are identical, and the product codes are different, and the new one has a higher version, the most common reason is that the older install is per user and the upgrade is per system (or the other way around). In VS setups that's the "Just me" setting, and it might be the default.

But yes, it is possible. It's nothing to do with the tool you use to build the MSI file, it's a feature of MSI files and Windows Installer.

Comment: Yes, I get two entries in Programs and Features.

Comment: Installing per User fixed it. Thank You!